# Find the max of two or more columns with pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns `A`,`B`. I need to create a column `C` such that for every record / row:

`C = max(A, B)`.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 306, accepted):

You can get the maximum like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [-2, 8, 1]})
>>> df
   A  B
0  1 -2
1  2  8
2  3  1
>>> df[["A", "B"]]
   A  B
0  1 -2
1  2  8
2  3  1
>>> df[["A", "B"]].max(axis=1)
0    1
1    8
2    3
```

and so:

```
>>> df["C"] = df[["A", "B"]].max(axis=1)
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  1 -2  1
1  2  8  8
2  3  1  3
```

If you know that "A" and "B" are the only columns, you could even get away with

```
>>> df["C"] = df.max(axis=1)
```

And you could use `.apply(max, axis=1)` too, I guess.

Answer (score 54):

@DSM's answer is perfectly fine in almost any normal scenario. But if you're the type of programmer who wants to go a little deeper than the surface level, you might be interested to know that it is a little faster to call numpy functions on the underlying [**`.to_numpy()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) (or `.values` for <0.24) array instead of directly calling the (cythonized) functions defined on the DataFrame/Series objects.

For example, you can use [**`ndarray.max()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html#numpy-ndarray-max) along the first axis.

```
# Data borrowed from @DSM's post.
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [-2, 8, 1]})
df
   A  B
0  1 -2
1  2  8
2  3  1

df['C'] = df[['A', 'B']].values.max(1)
# Or, assuming "A" and "B" are the only columns, 
# df['C'] = df.values.max(1) 
df

   A  B  C
0  1 -2  1
1  2  8  8
2  3  1  3
```

If your data has `NaN`s, you will need [**`numpy.nanmax`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.nanmax.html):

```
df['C'] = np.nanmax(df.values, axis=1)
df

   A  B  C
0  1 -2  1
1  2  8  8
2  3  1  3
```

---

You can also use `numpy.maximum.reduce`. [**`numpy.maximum`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) is a [ufunc (Universal Function)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/ufuncs.html), and [every ufunc has a `reduce`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html#numpy-ufunc-reduce):

```
df['C'] = np.maximum.reduce(df['A', 'B']].values, axis=1)
# df['C'] = np.maximum.reduce(df[['A', 'B']], axis=1)
# df['C'] = np.maximum.reduce(df, axis=1)
df

   A  B  C
0  1 -2  1
1  2  8  8
2  3  1  3
```

---

[image]

`np.maximum.reduce` and `np.max` appear to be more or less the same (for most normal sized DataFrames)—and happen to be a shade faster than `DataFrame.max`. I imagine this difference roughly remains constant, and is due to internal overhead (indexing alignment, handling NaNs, etc).

The graph was generated using [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot). Benchmarking code, for reference:

```
import pandas as pd
import perfplot

np.random.seed(0)
df_ = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 1000))

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.concat([df_] * n, ignore_index=True),
    kernels=[
        lambda df: df.assign(new=df.max(axis=1)),
        lambda df: df.assign(new=df.values.max(1)),
        lambda df: df.assign(new=np.nanmax(df.values, axis=1)),
        lambda df: df.assign(new=np.maximum.reduce(df.values, axis=1)),
    ],
    labels=['df.max', 'np.max', 'np.maximum.reduce', 'np.nanmax'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(0, 15)],
    xlabel='N (* len(df))',
    logx=True,
    logy=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

For finding max among multiple columns would be:

```
df[['A','B']].max(axis=1).max(axis=0)
```

Example:

```
df = 

                         A      B
timestamp                                
2019-11-20 07:00:16  14.037880  15.217879
2019-11-20 07:01:03  14.515359  15.878632
2019-11-20 07:01:33  15.056502  16.309152
2019-11-20 07:02:03  15.533981  16.740607
2019-11-20 07:02:34  17.221073  17.195145

print(df[['A','B']].max(axis=1).max(axis=0))
17.221073
```

Answer (score 1):

Just complementing the solutions presented, if anyone wants to include information from the origin column with the highest value:

```
selected_columns = df.columns

df["C"] = df[selected_columns].apply(max, axis=1)
df["from_column"] = df[selected_columns].idxmax(axis=1)
```

The idxmax() method returns a Series with the index of the maximum value for each column.
By specifying the column axis (axis='columns' or axis=1), the idxmax() method returns a Series with the index of the maximum value for each row. In the case of the example code, it fills a new column with a column name.
I haven't tried using numpy, but I liked the @cs95 answer to the main question.

Comment: I was looking exactly for this. It is giving me `ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not float64` however for the second line of your code. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: Edit: solution can be found here: https://towardsdatascience.com/create-new-column-based-on-other-columns-pandas-5586d87de73d