# Python Pandas add column for row-wise max value of selected columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, max

```
data = {'name' : ['bill', 'joe', 'steve'],
    'test1' : [85, 75, 85],
    'test2' : [35, 45, 83],
     'test3' : [51, 61, 45]}
frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to add a new column that shows the max value for each row.

desired output:

```
 name test1 test2 test3 HighScore
 bill  75    75    85    85
 joe   35    45    83    83 
 steve  51   61    45    61
```

**Sometimes**

```
frame['HighScore'] = max(data['test1'], data['test2'], data['test3'])
```

works but most of the time gives this error:

**ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()**

Why does it only work sometimes?  Is there another way of doing it?

Comment: Faster solutions along with performance comparisons for this particular operation can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54299629/4909087).

Answer (score 135, accepted):

```
>>> frame['HighScore'] = frame[['test1','test2','test3']].max(axis=1)
>>> frame
    name  test1  test2  test3  HighScore
0   bill     85     35     51         85
1    joe     75     45     61         75
2  steve     85     83     45         85
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out what the (axis=1) does?

Comment: @RanjanR.Lamichhane In short, `max(axis=1)` gets the rowwise max, while `max(axis=0)` gets the column-wise max.  Take a look at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html

Answer (score 15):

```
>>> frame['HighScore'] = frame[['test1','test2','test3']].apply(max, axis=1)
>>> frame
    name  test1  test2  test3  HighScore
0   bill     85     35     51        85
1    joe     75     45     61        75
2  steve     85     83     45        85
```

Comment: This method works better by ignoring NA's when calculating max by default

Comment: Is there a way to get the name of the column. e.g. HighScore = 85 in the first row the column name is test1 for that high score

Answer (score 3):

if a `max` or `min` value between multiple columns in a `df` is to be determined then use:

```
df['Z']=df[['A','B','C']].apply(np.max,axis=1)
```