# Calculating Average True Range column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, technical-indicator

I am trying to add an Average True Range column to a dataframe that contains historical stock data.

The code I am using so far is:

```
def add_atr_to_dataframe (dataframe):
    dataframe['ATR1'] = abs (dataframe['High'] - dataframe['Low'])
    dataframe['ATR2'] = abs (dataframe['High'] - dataframe['Close'].shift())
    dataframe['ATR3'] = abs (dataframe['Low'] - dataframe['Close'].shift())
    dataframe['TrueRange'] = max (dataframe['ATR1'], dataframe['ATR2'], dataframe['ATR3'])
    return dataframe
```

The last line, containing the max function, gives the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I have googled for days in trying to learn how to resolve this error, or do the code in a better way, etc and have found nothing that helps me along.

Any help in the following would be much appreciated:

1. How to resolve the error
2. How to do the code in a better way - I do not mean that I have to code it this way and there may be better ways to do it.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 6):

**tl;dr** Use

```
dataframe[['ATR1', 'ATR2', 'ATR3']].max(axis=1)
```

---

**Explanation**

You can't use the built-in `max` on Pandas objects. Since the first argument you are passing to `max` is iterable, [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) signature of `max` is invoked:

> `max`*(iterable* **[** *, key* **]**)

This implicitly performs a `__nonzero__` (truthiness) check on the first argument to determine whether the iterable is empty, which is where your error is coming from. Numpy and Pandas objects do not coerce to booleans by design.

You are looking for something like this:

```
dataframe['TrueRange'] = dataframe[['ATR1', 'ATR2', 'ATR3']].max(axis=1)
```

This computes the maximum of the `ATR*` columns along the horizontal axis and returns the result as a `Series`, which you then add as a new `TrueRange` column in your dataframe.

Comment: Igor, your code works perfectly! Thank you so much for responding so quickly and with such a great solution! You just ended days of frustration for me.

Comment: No problem, see edit for why you are getting that specific error.

Comment: Also, I was too hasty on the answer, your question has a duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033111/python-pandas-max-value-of-selected-columns) :) the solution they suggest is identical

Comment: I just noticed that duplicate a minute ago and did not come across it in days of googling and searching this site - sorry I did not find it earlier and thanks again for taking the time to help.

Answer (score -1):

not exactly sure if I get what you mean, but I'd suggest using [pd.max()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) instead of *max()* in the problematic row.