# How to select max and min value in a row for selected columns

Tags: python, pandas

Let us say we have the following table
[image]

and I want to find max and min value for every row for a set of specific columns (let's say CENSUS2010POP, ESTIMATESBASE1010, POPESTIMATE2010). 
How to do it with Pandas?

Comment: for finding max value from column.. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741759/find-maximum-value-of-a-column-and-return-the-corresponding-row-values-using-pan

Comment: @HarshaBiyani I know hot to find max value in column... but I need it for a row and consider only few columns in a row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas max value of selected columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033111/python-pandas-max-value-of-selected-columns)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need [`min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) and [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html):

```
df_subset=df.set_index('CTYNAME')[['CENSUS2010POP', 'ESTIMATESBASE1010', 'POPESTIMATE2010']]
df1 = df_subset.min(axis=1)
print (df1)

df2= df_subset.max(axis=1)
print (df2)
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CTYNAME':['Alabama','Autauga County','Baldwin County','Barbour County'],
                   'CENSUS2010POP':[4,5,6,2],
                   'ESTIMATESBASE1010':[7,8,9,3],
                   'POPESTIMATE2010':[1,3,5,5]})

print (df)
   CENSUS2010POP         CTYNAME  ESTIMATESBASE1010  POPESTIMATE2010
0              4         Alabama                  7                1
1              5  Autauga County                  8                3
2              6  Baldwin County                  9                5
3              2  Barbour County 

df_subset=df.set_index('CTYNAME')[['CENSUS2010POP', 'ESTIMATESBASE1010', 'POPESTIMATE2010']]
df1 = df_subset.max(axis=1) - df_subset.min(axis=1)
print (df1)
CTYNAME
Alabama           6
Autauga County    5
Baldwin County    4
Barbour County    3
dtype: int64

print (df1.nlargest(1).reset_index(name='top1'))
   CTYNAME  top1
0  Alabama     6
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following data `df`

```
    a   b   c
    0.2 1.2 9
    0.5 2.1 1.1
    3.9 0.2 1.9
    4.6 3.3 7.8
```

If you want is to find max value for each row BUT for only few columns, you could do column slicing (for example, columns a and b only) as follows :

```
df.assign(max_value=(df[df.columns[0:2]]).values.max(1))
```

The result will be:

```
    a        b       c    max_value
0   0.2     1.2     9.0     1.2
1   0.5     2.1     1.1     2.1
2   3.9     0.2     1.9     3.9
3   4.6     3.3     7.8     4.6
```

Comment: How about dynamic columns and get the max value except the first two columns?