# How to iterate through pandas series without using boolean indexing

Tags: python, pandas

I have come across this problem several times. The problem is that I cannot understand how to iterate through a pandas series in a DataFrame to access individual values.

In this particular case I am trying to find the maximum value for each row in a specific column in a pandas DataFrame, some rows of which contain lists.

`df` is as such:

```
  Date            Number
0 2000-01-01        [1.0]
1 2000-01-02        [2.2, 5, 7.8]
2 2000-01-03        [8.2]
3 2000-01-04        [4, 11.78, 24.66]
```

The attempted code has been the following in relation to this question:

[Find the max of two or more columns with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169170/how-should-i-take-the-max-of-2-columns-in-a-dataframe-and-make-it-another-column)

However I am trying to replace the current column and for some reason it seems to provide my column with an empty list.

Desired output would be the following:

```
  Date            Number
0 2000-01-01        1.0
1 2000-01-02        7.8
2 2000-01-03        8.2
3 2000-01-04        24.66
```

Taking the max of the row and replacing the original. Any suggestions as to how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `if-else`:

```
import ast
df.Number = df.Number.apply(ast.literal_eval)

df.Number = [max(i, default=0) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in df.Number]
```

Alternative with `apply`:

```
df.Number = df.Number.apply(lambda i: max(i, default=0) if isinstance(i, list) else i)
```

---

```
print (df)
         Date  Number
0  2000-01-01       1
1  2000-01-02       7
2  2000-01-03       8
3  2000-01-04      24
```

Comment: No error occurring here although multiple numbers in lists for each row therefore not taking the max of each row.

Comment: @geds133 - are values lists and integers? If use `import ast
` and `df.Number = df.Number.apply(ast.literal_eval)` before my solution it working?

Comment: Numbers are floats in the lists in my DataFrame. Should have made the example floats and therefore have edited. Would this make a difference?

Comment: @geds133 - I think there is no problem with floats. If check `print (df.Number.apply(type))` it return correct lists and integers ?

Comment: It appears the type is `<class 'str'>` although an example of a row of `df.Number` looks as such: `[403.578, 403.578, 403.578, 586.9599999999999,...`

Comment: ok, so use `import ast and df.Number = df.Number.apply(ast.literal_eval)` before my solution

Comment: Obtain error: `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`

Comment: @geds133 - It meas there are some empry list(s) - what need in output for it? `0` or `NaN` ?

Comment: 0 would be most appropriate although

`In[38]: df.Number.isnull().sum()

Out[38]: 0`

Comment: @geds133 - so use `df.Number = [max(i, default=0) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in df.Number]`

Comment: Solution has worked, many thanks for your help as always @jezrael

Answer (score 1):

Your data is messy. I suggest you first try and ensure consistent data is fed into your dataframe, ideally via `float`series. Failing this, you can use a nested `try` / `except` to cover any number of scenarios covered by your messy data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dat': ['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02', '2000-01-03', '2000-01-04',
                           '2000-01-05', '2000-01-06', '2000-01-07'],
                   'Number': ['1', ['2.2', '5.0', '7.8'], '8', ['4', '11.78', '24.66'],
                              np.nan, None, []]})

def calc_max(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except TypeError:
        try:
            return max(map(float, x), default=np.nan)
        except TypeError:
            return np.nan

# apply function to each value in 'Number'
df['Number'] = list(map(calc_max, df['Number']))

print(df)

          Dat  Number
0  2000-01-01    1.00
1  2000-01-02    7.80
2  2000-01-03    8.00
3  2000-01-04   24.66
4  2000-01-05     NaN
5  2000-01-06     NaN
6  2000-01-07     NaN
```

#### Why your data is messy

Check `df['Number'].dtype`. If your data is clean / Pandas-friendly, you'll see `int` or `float`. But here you see `object`. This represents a sequence of points to arbitrary Python objects. Then some of those objects are lists, and a list is itself is a sequence of pointers. Hence you have a nested list of pointers as opposed to a numeric array stored in a contiguous block of memory.

Comment: Why is my data classified as messy? Thanks.

Comment: Many thanks for explanation. Will keep in mind for future encounters of this type.