# Python : Adding conditional column to pandas dataframe, more pythonic solution?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm adding a column to a dataframe where the column values are determined by comparing two *other* columns in the dataframe. The code to add the column is:

```
lst = []
for x in range(len(df)):
    if df['ColumnA'][x] > df['ColumnB'][x]:
        lst.append(df['ColumnB'][x])
    else:
        lst.append(df['ColumnA'][x])

df['ColumnC'] = lst
```

My question is, is there a more efficient/pythonic way to do this? I have been advised in the past to be wary if I'm every looping through every row of a dataframe, so wanted to see if I was missing something. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the max of two or more columns with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169170/find-the-max-of-two-or-more-columns-with-pandas)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just take the minimum:

```
df['ColumnC'] = df[['ColumnA', 'ColumnB']].min(1)
```

Comment: do you know how this compares perf. wise to np.where off the top? No worries if not, good solution!

Comment: Probably `np.where`, but don't prematurely optimize.. Write good, understandable code. Then discover bottlenecks and optimize them.

Answer (score 2):

Use `numpy.where`

```
df['ColumnC'] = np.where(df['ColumnA'] > df['ColumnB'], df['ColumnB'], df['ColumnA'])
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more code than other solutions but arguably more generalizable

```
mask = df[ColumnA] > df[ColumnB]
df[ColumnC] = pd.Series(index=df.index)
df[ColumnC].loc[mask] = df[ColumnA].loc[mask]
df[ColumnC].loc[~mask] = df[ColumnB].loc[~mask]
```